# Pandas groupby() not accepting apply() method with options

Tags: python, pandas

Using the following example:

```
arrays = [['one','one','one','two','two','two'],[1,2,3,1,2,3]]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zip(*arrays)),columns=['A','B'])
```

As expected this apply works over the groupby object:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, window=3, center=True))
```

However, when specifying options for apply it throws up an error:

```
df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: pd.rolling_mean(x, window=3, center=True), raw=True)    
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'raw'
```

I can't figure out where I have gone wrong.

Note: It seems to work fine for non MultiIndex objects

[Pandas: Timing difference between Function and Apply to Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23100450/pandas-timing-difference-between-function-and-apply-to-series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different `apply` methods for `DataFrame`s and `GroupBy` objects. Only `DataFrame.apply` has a `raw` argument:

```
help(df.apply)
# Output:
Help on method apply in module pandas.core.frame:

apply(self, func, axis=0, broadcast=False, raw=False, reduce=None, args=(), **kwds) method of pandas.core.frame.DataFrame instance
    Applies function along input axis of DataFrame.
...
```

Whereas for the groupby:

```
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
help(grouped.apply)
# Output:
Help on method apply in module pandas.core.groupby:

apply(self, func, *args, **kwargs) method of pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy instance
```